# Google Cloud Messaging device not received notifications. (No "Registered Apps" link)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem

I try to register google cloud messaging application to sent push notifications on android devices from my webserver(HTTP, only for sending notifications).
Several months ago have already created android application and server by reading this [article](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) and they are work together very good.

But now I wanted to create new project and new api key and new project number.

I tried to read [article](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) again and do it step by step.
In paragraph "Obtaining an API Key" there is step "In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth > **Registered apps**.". But I have no link "Registered apps".
Here is screenshots
[image: screenshot]

I tried old google console, but not found this link too.

I skipped this step, and successfully registered server key:
*To Obtain an API Key : On the left panel use link "APIs & auth" -> "Credentials" -> Public API access -> "Create New key" button->"Create New Server Key"*
[image: screenshot2]

After that android application has successfully subscribed to receiving notifications, and when server send message gcm returns:
{"multicast_id":8945377945815738093,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1389010664482946%4335aee7f9fd7ecd"}]}, but device does not receive any notification(but it receives with old project number if I rollback server to use old api key).

I think issue happens because I did not make step **"Under Android identification, type the package name for your app."** as written in [article](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html), but I cannot add it, because I cannot see link "Registered apps". May be I should enter application package it in some other place? Or I do not need to enter it at all? In this case should I add it when subscribe to receive it in android?

Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, You have created a server project only.As per the new Google api console, You need to create new android key also(APPID/SENDER ID). When these two(server key and android key) are under same project then only you will get the push notifications successfully. otherwise you will get the error.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. As I am understand, Android key only need if I want to send notification from Android to somewhere, but I should send notifications only from server to devices. I tried to create Android key, with SHA1;package_of_my_application, console generates me new Android Api Key, but I cannot use it anywhere. After creating AndrApiKey, device still successfully subscribes, server sends notifications with "success:1" status, but device receives nothing:(

Comment: First read the link : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [Netmera](http://netmera.com/). It is easy to implement and register push notifications. They also provide a wide reporting mechanism for your notifications. You should give it a try.